# Regular expression capture with optional trailing underscore and number

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression that will match the base string without the optional trailing number (`_123`). *e.g.:*

`lorem_ipsum_test1_123` -> capture **lorem_ipsum_test1**

`lorem_ipsum_test2` -> capture **lorem_ipsum_test2**

I tried using the following expression, but it would only work when there is a trailing _number.

`/(.+)(?>_[0-9]+)/
/(.+)(?>_[0-9]+)?/`

Similarly, adding the `?` (zero or more) quantifier only worked when there is no trailing _number, otherwise, the trailing _number would just be part of the first capture.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, but why not simply remove the `/_\d+$/`? `s.replace(/_\d+$/, '')`?

Comment: @Guillaume Did any of the below solutions work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following expression:

```
^(?:[^_]+_)+(?!\d+$)[^_]+
```

- `^` Anchor beginning of string.
- `(?:[^_]+_)+` Repeated non capturing group. Negated character set for anything other than a `_`, followed by a `_`.
- `(?!\d+$)` Negative lookahead for digits at the end of the string.
- `[^_]+` Negated character set for anything other than a `_`.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fUeKVu/1).

Please note that the `\n` in the character sets in the Regex demo are only for demonstration purposes, and should by all means be removed when using as a pattern in Javascript.

---

**Javascript demo:**

```js
var myString = "lorem_ipsum_test1_123";
var myRegexp = /^(?:[^_]+_)+(?!\d+$)[^_]+/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[0]);

var myString = "lorem_ipsum_test2"
var myRegexp = /^(?:[^_]+_)+(?!\d+$)[^_]+/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might match any character and use a negative lookahead that asserts that what follows is not an underscore, one or more digits and the end of the string:

`^(?:(?!_\d+$).)*`

Explanation

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead to assert what is on the right side is not

    - `_\d+$`Match an underscore, one or more digits and assert end of the string
  - `.)` Match any character and close negative lookahead
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat zero or more times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GhKAAa/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "lorem_ipsum_test1_123",
  "lorem_ipsum_test2"
];
let pattern = /^(?:(?!_\d+$).)*/;
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + s.match(pattern)[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for

```
/^(.*?)(?:_\d+)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B7GVpH/1). The point here is that the first dot pattern must be non-greedy and the `_\d+` should be wrapped with an optional non-capturing group and the whole pattern (especially the end) must be enclosed with anchors.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible due to the non-greedy (*"lazy"*) quantifier `*?`
- `(?:_\d+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `_` and then 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

However, it seems easier to use a mere replacing approach,

```
s = s.replace(/_\d+$/, '')
```

If the string ends with `_` and 1+ digits, the substring will get removed, else, the string will not change.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B7GVpH/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the string contains the trailing number. If it does you get only the other part. Otherwise you get the whole string.

```
var str = "lorem_ipsum_test1_123"

if(/_[0-9]+$/.test(str)) {
   console.log(str.match(/(.+)(?=_[0-9]+)/g))
} else {
   console.log(str)
}
```

Or, a lot more concise:

```
str = str.replace(/_[0-9]+$/g, "")
```